# Change values in dataset based on other value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with my dataset.

Here are some values of my dataset.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4XZ8.png

My problem is that I need to create a function that replaces the value in column "Cholesterol" based on column "Age".

```
for i in heart_disease_1.Age:
  if i <= 35:
    heart_disease_1.replace(0, 194)
```

I need to change values in "Cholesterol" that are "0" to value "194" if in column "Age" is 35 or less.

I tried other functions for replacing but it either change all values under 36 to that number or nothing happened.

Thank you.

Comment: This appears to be pandas, please tag [tag:pandas]. Also, show what else you tried.

Comment: You're not assigning to the column "Cholesterol", you have to assign to it using `df.loc[]` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
heart_disease_1.loc[(heart_disease_1['Cholesterol'] == 0) & (heart_disease_1['Age'] <=35), 'Cholesterol'] = 194
```

Example:

```
d = {'Age': [49, 48, 35], 'Cholesterol': [180, 204, 0]}
heart_disease_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
heart_disease_1.loc[(heart_disease_1['Cholesterol'] == 0) & (heart_disease_1['Age'] <=35), 'Cholesterol'] = 194
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using loops in pandas, you can use boolean masks as indexes inside assignments, then this becomes a one-liner:

```
hd.loc[(hd['Cholesterol']==0) & (hd['Age']<=35), 'Cholesterol'] = 194
```

Note that we must parenthesise the subexpressions `(hd['Cholesterol']==0)` and `(hd['Age']<=35)` to avoid operator precedence messing us up.

Comment: By the way, a short name like `hd` is better for legibility than `heart_disease_1`, on this case we use the name three times in one line, and 72/80-character linelength is desirable for legibility.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an error in your loop, you don't want to do [for i in list.age], you want [for i in list], if i.age <=35 ,do replace if that makes sense.

```
for i in heard_disease_1:
  if i.Age <= 35:
    i.Cholesterol.replace(0, 194)
```

I believe that should get you to where you are trying to go. Let me know if it works.  Also, you may need to replace `i.Cholesterol` with `i.<whatever the column name is>`.
Hopefully that helps,
~X

Comment: This does not work -> 'str' object has no attribute 'Age'

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean mask to change it. Don't use loop in pandas.

```
mask = (heart_disease_1.Age<=35)&(heart_disease_1.Cholesterol==0)
heart_disease_1.loc[mask, "Cholesterol"] = 194
```